# Javascript regex split a string with new lines when text is surrounded by quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use the `split` string method to split a string when a text is quoted.  For example, I want this string:

```
Some text  

"This is what
I want to catch"

Some more text
```

To become a string array such as:

```
0: "Some text"
1: "This is what↵I want to catch"
2: "↵↵Some more text"
```

To achieve that, I am calling:

```
inputText.split(/"((.+)|\s)+"/)
```

This doesn't work as it creates the array:

```
0: "Some text"
1: "I want to catch"
2: "I want to catch"
3: "↵↵Some more text"
```

Any idea how to achieve what I want?

I cannot use look-behinds and look-aheads, because I still want the quotes to be a part of the match.
My goal is to split the string when a text is surrounded by quotes, but not have the quotes themselves in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As desired you may use this regex in `split`:

```
/\n*(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)")?\n+/
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `\n*`: Match 0+ line breaks
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `"`: Match opening `"`
  - `(`: Start capture group

    - `[^"\\]*`: match 0+ of any characters that are not `"` and not `\`
    - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*`: Match an escaped character followed by 0+ of any characters that are not `"` and not `\`. Repeat this group 0 or more times
  - `)`: End capture group #1
  - `"`: Match closing `"`
- `)?`: End non-capture group. `?` makes this group optional
- `\n+`: Match 1+ line breaks

**Code:**

```js
const s = `Some text

"This is what
I want to catch"

Some more text`

var m = s.split(/\n*(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)")?\n+/)

console.log(m)
```

---

*Alternatively*, you may use this regex in Javascript to **match** quoted string that allows escaping of quotes as well:

```sh
/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"\n]+/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N9E0qw/2)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `"`: match opening `"`
- `[^"\\]*`: match 0+ of any characters that are not `"` and not `\`
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*`: Match an escaped character followed by 0+ of any characters that are not `"` and not `\`. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `"`: Match closing `"`
- `|`: OR
- `[^"\n]`: Match other lines without newline or `"`

**Code:**

```js
const s = `Some text

"This is what
I want to catch"

Some more text`

var m = s.match(/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"\n]+/g)

console.log(m)
```

Comment: I am not trying to do a match but a `split`, which will return every group as a separate element in the resulting array. This solution returns an array with more than 30 elements. In my example, I only want 3. :(

Comment: Oops there was a typo that caused (I missed a `+` which was there in demo link). There will be only 3 array in output, please check updated answer.

Comment: This works well with a `match`, but not with a `split`. It returns an array with 4 entries: two empty and two new lines, but none with text. Could you write an example that uses split instead of match, please?

Comment: @RyanPergent: Answer updated with `split` code.

Comment: Thanks. I had to slightly edit your regex to make it not get the quotes in the group, but it works :). The final split regex: `\n*"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"\n+`

Comment: ok answer updated with fine tuned regex and explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split over `"`. You can also truncate the leading and trailing new line characters.

```js
const s = `Some text
"This is what
I want to catch"
Some more text`

console.log(s.split('"'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will cause a split even if I have a single double quote. I want to specifically catch text that is surrounded by quotes both at the start and at the end.